# suppression within journey builder to receive only 1 email with certain days

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

How to Create a suppression within the journey so that a customer receives only 1
email in 1 week? Can I use this flow,

1. send the email
2. exit the customer from the journey after 1 week

Is this correct?

Comment: Are you talking about one email per week from the instance or one email from one journey?

Comment: @SwatiMishra one email from a journey

Comment: Yes, you can exit the contact from the journey after 1 week, provided you have set the re-entry criteria on journey settings as  'Re-entry only after exiting'

Comment: @swatimishra thanks a lot for the information